# iOS 9 app thinning long download/install time (30 min)

Tags: ios, ios9

I have an app on the AppStore and because it has a lot of files in the project (about 3000) the download/install (not really sure when the app thinning happens) is very slow because it seems Apple is checking each file (I think) for it's @2x/@3x version.

The problem is that most of the files are actually SVG's and they don't have @2x/@3x.
From my tests the download time varies between 15 minutes (iPhone 5) and 30 minutes (iPhone 5S) for a 60 mb app which is way too much considering 500mb ones take 5 minutes on my WiFi.

Besides the obvious solution where I zip everything and unzip it on the first start in the documents folder is there anything else I could do?

Comment: Don't think there's a lot you could do really, to each and every iPhone user, their connectivity to the app store is not your concern. Have you enabled bitcode in your build settings? Minify SVG's? Use PNG shrinker?

Comment: See the blog post [Creating Scaled Images With PDF Vectors](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/creating-scaled-images-with-pdf-vectors.html) for more information on using PFD images and how Apple handles the scaling.